# JSP- Cannot import another JSP file

Tags: jsp

I am trying to call my other JSP page in my current JSP page. Basically in my `editUrl.jsp`, I want to include `genurl.jsp` as well.

From what I know, the way to do it is either:

```
<jsp:include page="file.jsp" />
```

or

```
 <%@ include file="filename" %>
```

So I followed the method and did it like below:

```
<%@ include file="genurl.jsp" %>
```

When I run my program, it throws a nullpointer exception meaning it couldn't locate this file. I checked my root folder and they are both located in the same folder. Here is a screenshot for reference.

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong?

My genurl.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@include file="../../../WEB-INF/jspf/mcre.jspf" %>
<%@include file="../../../WEB-INF/jspf/session.jspf"%>

<%@ page import="com.htasia.panton9.Core.Settings.SettingsFacadeLocal" %>
<%@page import="com.htasia.panton9.Utilities.CoreUtil,
        com.htasia.MCRE.File.*,
        com.htasia.MCRE.Types.*,
        com.htasia.panton9.Core.Node.*,
        com.htasia.panton9.Entities.Core.Node,
        com.htasia.panton9.Entities.MCRE.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.persistence.EntityManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.security.SecureRandom" %>
<%@ page import="java.math.BigInteger" %>


<html>



<%

    String relPath = "../../../";
    NodeFacadeLocal nFacade = null;

    InitialContext ntx = new InitialContext();

    try {
        nFacade = (NodeFacadeLocal) ntx.lookup("java:comp/env/node");

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





%>

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=relPath%>js/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=relPath%>js/jquery/jquery-panton-win.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=relPath%>js/jquery/jquery-panton-win-2.js"></script>
    <title>Generate URL</title>





</head>


<body>
<div id="table123" style="overflow:scroll;height:400px;width:100%;overflow:auto">

<table class="filesTbl">
    <tr>
        <th width="1%">
            Checkbox
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
             No
        </th>
        <th width="20%">
            File Name
        </th>
        <th width="50%">
            Unique URL
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
            Edit
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
            Copy
        </th>
        <th width="1%">
            Email
        </th>

    </tr>

<%
    //need to input logic to populate data on each row

    int counter=0;
    int tally=0;

    String[] split = request.getParameter("nodeID").split(",",0);
    for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){

        long file=Long.parseLong(split[i]);

        List files = fileFacade.list_items(file);
        for (Iterator rstltr = files.iterator(); rstltr.hasNext();) {
            Fmedia fv = (Fmedia) rstltr.next();
            Node nd = nodeFacade.get(fv.getNodeid(), false);
            // Fmedia fm = fileFacade.get_file(fv.getNodeid());



            int count = 0;
            count++;
            long fileid= nd.getNodeid();

      SettingsFacadeLocal settingFacade = (SettingsFacadeLocal)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/settings");
        String redirectURL = settingFacade.get("SERVER_URL").getAtval();
        //declare a timestamp for unique URL
        // String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
        // String hash = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(timeStamp);

        SecureRandom secureRandom=new SecureRandom();
        byte[] token = new byte[12];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(token);
        String hash= new BigInteger(1, token).toString(12);





%>


    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%">

            <script>


 // function to copy multiple URL links

                function copymultiplelink() {

                    var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
                        alert("Please select at least one file.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var filesList = [];
                    var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    $fileChecks.each(function() {
                        filesList.push($(this).val());
                    });

                    alert("You have copied " + filesList.length+ " URL");
                    copyURL(filesList.join("\n"),false);

                }

                //function to call the edit the page
                function editURL(filename,url){

            var x=document.getElementById("table123");
                x.style.display="none";




                   $('body').pWin("open", {
                       x: 260,
                       y: 47,
                       height: 450,
                       width: 881,
                        title: "Edit:Advance Configuration",
                        skinMode:'dialog',
                        iframe:true,
                        url: "editUrl.jsp",

                        data: {


                        filename:filename,
                            link:url





                        },
                        offResize:true,
                        offMove:true,
                        onTitle:false,
                        offBottom:true

                    });


                   // x.style.display="none";








                }



            </script>

            <!--Display Checkbox   -->
            <input type="checkbox" class="fileCheck" id="<%=tally=tally+1%>" value="<%=redirectURL+"/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?f0="+nd.getNodeid()+"&ts="+hash%>"  />&nbsp;


        </td>

        <td>
            <!--Display No   -->
            <% counter=counter+1;
                out.print(counter);

            %>


        </td>
        <td width="28%">

            <!-- Display Filename   -->
            <%=nd.getNodedesc()%>



        </td>
        <td width="100%">
            <!-- Display Unique URL -->


            <%=redirectURL+"/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?f0="+nd.getNodeid()+"&ts="+hash%>
            <%

                fileFacade.insert_url(nd.getNodeid(),"f0="+nd.getNodeid()+"&ts="+hash);

                //fileFacade.insert_url(nd.getNodeid(),"{syscont url}/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?{url});

            %>


        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Display EDIT/DEL -->
            <input type="button" value="Edit URL" onclick="editURL('<%=nd.getNodedesc()%>','<%=redirectURL+"/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?f0="+nd.getNodeid()+"&ts="+hash%>')" >

        </td>
        <td> <!-- Display COPY feature -->

            <input type="button" value="Copy URL" onclick="copyURL('<%=redirectURL+"/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?f0="+nd.getNodeid()+"&ts="+hash%>',true)">

        </td>


    </tr>

    </tbody>


<%}}
%>


    <script>
        function copyURL(url,showMsg) {
            var copyText = url;
            var el = document.createElement('textarea');
            el.value = copyText;
            el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
            el.style = {
                position: 'absolute',
                left: '-9999px'
            };
            document.body.appendChild(el);
            el.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            document.body.removeChild(el);
            if(showMsg==true) {
                alert("You have copied the URL");
            }
        }
    </script>





</table>






<!--Copy button to copy multiple links -->

<div class="wrapper">
    <button type="button" onclick="copymultiplelink()"> Copy Selected URL</button>
</div>
</div>
<style>


    .wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 90%;
        left: 5%;
    }

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Full exception trace:

```
[2019-03-25T13:17:18.792+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1553491038792] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.repository.file.url.editUrl_jsp._jspService(editUrl_jsp.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
]]

[2019-03-25T13:48:44.442+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=185 _ThreadName=ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[glassfish-web].StandardHost[server].StandardContext[]]] [timeMillis: 1553492924442] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Session event listener threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener.getSessionContext(WeldTerminalListener.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener.sessionDestroyed(WeldTerminalListener.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:910)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.isValid(StandardSession.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.processExpires(StandardManager.java:1056)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:6371)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1823)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1812)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
]]
```

Comment: Edited my post pls help

Comment: The code in file "genurl.jsp" bothers you. Post the code if available.

Comment: Yea because if I removed it,it works.

Comment: Edited my post, it might be appear a bit long but it's better to post it

Comment: It is throwing NPE, means in your jsp java code is throwing NPE. While importing it, it is throwing so no problem with your import. Problem with your genurl.jsp file. Add not null condition if required.

Comment: @Sudhakar I'm able to call a variable from genurl.jsp but it would still throw NPE. What do you mean adding not null condition?